# setState in $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

When `this.setState()` is used within the `$.get` scope I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

It works fine outside the `$.get` scope.

How can I fix this?

```
$.get(APIURL, function (data) {
   this.setState({resdata: "This is a new state"});
});
```

I'm not sure what is the best practice to replace jQuery AJAX to other small AJAX libraries.

Comment: I'm guessing `setState` is some function that is available on whatever `this` is outside the callback function, but it's not very clear

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can save a reference to the outer `this`:

```
var that = this;
$.get(APIURL, function (data) {
   that.setState({resdata: "This is a new state"});
});
```

Or use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/):

```
$.get(APIURL, $.proxy(function (data) {
   this.setState({resdata: "This is a new state"});
}, this));
```

The `this` you use inside the function normally refers to the jqXHR object, ref http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You should wrap the setState call in an isMounted check.  `if (that.isMounted()) that.setState...`, or ensure the callback isn't called in componentWillUnmount (by saving a jqxhr reference and aborting it).

Comment: `$.get(APIURL, function (data) {
      this.setState({resdata: "This is a new state"});
    }.bind(this));`

`bind` is also available with some browser compatibility. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @banyan `$.proxy` is jquery's convenience wrapper for `call`/`bind`

Comment: `isMounted()` will be deprecated: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use bind(this) either, like in the React Documentation:

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Here's a snippet of code:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
      var lastGist = result[0];
      this.setState({
        username: lastGist.owner.login,
        lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },
```